# Importing single ArcPy functions?

Tags: arcpy

If I wanted to import a single function, such as `RasterToPolygon_conversion`, how would I do that without import all of ArcPy through `import arcpy`?

I'm trying to reduce the time it takes at program startup, and I don't need all of ArcPy.

Comment: This answer from the software Stack Exchange might be useful: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/187471/1622

Comment: @RichardMorgan So I got `from arcpy import RasterToPolygon_conversion as rtp` working, but it takes just as long to load as if I had just done `import arcpy`. Should it not be faster?

Comment: @RichardMorgan I think you should introduce and link to that [softwareengineering.se] answer in one here.

Comment: No, it cannot be faster. If you research what it takes to make a site package, you'll see that building object references takes time. While you might only need one function, it needs access to thousands,  and that is what takes so much time

Answer (score 4):

One thing to note about `arcpy`, is that Esri has created aliases for most of the tools for your convenience.  If you look at the `toolbox.py` script inside the `arcpy` folder in the ArcGIS install, you can see that they are using relative imports to import every tool so they can be used from just the `arcpy` namespace.

For example, you can use the syntax `arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion` because they give it that alias like this in `toolbox.py`:

`from .conversion import RasterToPolygon as RasterToPolygon_conversion`

The `RasterToPolygon` function actually lives inside the `conversion.py` file in the ArcGIS install directory.  The way I usually access it is by the package namespace, which is `arcpy.conversion.RasterToPolygon`.

As @Vince mentioned, `arcpy` is a package, and therefore will have some overhead building object references to all the classes and functions.  You can import the specific functions, but you still will not be able to bypass the overhead of accessing `arcpy` as a package.

You can test this by using the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module.  You will find that there is **not a lot of difference** in timing of doing the following import tests (usually ~3 - 4 seconds):

```
from arcpy.conversion import RasterToPolygon

from arcpy import RasterToPolygon_conversion
```

However, you can get a gain in speed by temporarily appending the folder one level inside the `arcpy` package to your `PYTHONPATH` with the `sys` module.  The import time on this was roughly ~1.5 seconds, so almost half the time:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy')
# we can now just access the conversion module
from conversion import RasterToPolygon
```

However, I do not think I would recommend doing it this way.  This is probably not safe as the individual modules will probably not be functioning as a package anymore if you had not previously imported `arcpy`.

Comment: The two `from` examples each take just as long as `import arcpy`. Atop that, `from arcpy.conversion import RasterToPolygon as RTP` doesn't work when I try `RTP(raster, outfile, "NO_SIMPLIFY", "Value")` as it says it is not defined.